# Passing a python Value into form through a button ref in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using the following view function to iterate over 3 values (`Channels_collection`) within a form:

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('adray/home page.html')
    Channels_collection = ['You Tube', 'Google search', 'Google search']
    return render(request, 'adray/home page.html', {'Channels_collection': Channels_collection})
```

Within the home page.html, i'm creating 3 bootstrap modals using a for loop using the 3 of the values that were passed by the view.
These modals, that are launched through a button, (the `"start test"` button, its really a link)  redirect the user into another input data form, as following:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div id="page-inner">

                <div class="row">

                   {% for channel_type in Channels_collection %}
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Testing {{ channel_type}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                              Click  To launch {{ channel_type}} Experiment
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Set Up {{ channel_type}} Experiment</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                           Welcome to our tests, set up your experiment for  {{ channel_type}}    </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <form action="{% url 'input_data'  %}" method="POST">
                                            <a href="{% url 'input_data'  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Start Test</a>
                                               </form>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}

    </div>

        </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

Each iteration of the modal has its own `channel_type` value, my question is:
How can i save the value of channel type, when the button is being clicked?

Any help on that would be great!

Comment: the reason that you haven't got an answer yet is because it's not bvery clear what you are asking.

Comment: just edited it, hope it makes more sense now

Comment: You need to send an HTTP post to the server using ajax or just plain old form submit.

Comment: thanks, ill try that